# Choosing $P_0$ in Point-Normal form given vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I have as knowns some 3 points which I am fitting a plane to.

Given that I have calculated the normal vector as the cross of the vectors defined by those points, is it legal to choose $P_0$ as one of those three points that I used to calculate the normal vector?

It'll go into a function that looks something like
$f(P_1,P_2,P_3) = (P_i - P_0)^T \hat n$

My intuition says yes, just want to be sure, been a while since linear algebra.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand what you're asking.  You've found the normal, so you know the equations is of the form $ax+by+cz=d,$ where you've computed $a,b,c$ and you want to substitute one the of the given points to find $d.$  Yes, that's the way to do it.

Comment: @saulspatz Well yes, but this is the equation of a plane, not a surface, so I am talking about $ax + by + cz = 0$. Or specifically the vector dot product of $(P-P_{0x},P-P_{0y},P-P_{0z}) \bullet \hat n = 0$

I am wondering if it is legal to use one of the three points used to obtain $\hat n$ in this equation as $P_0$

Comment: No, the equation of a plane is $ax+by+cz=d.$  When $d=0$ it's a plane through the origin.  But yes, it's okay for $P_0$ to be one of the given points.

Comment: erm, yes, right. yes. Thanks, got it.